# Kubernetes deployment on local Ubuntu cluster

Tags: deployment, ubuntu-14.04, kubernetes, etcd, connection-refused

I'm simply trying to install Kubernetes on local Ubuntu cluster using the original documentation.(http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/ubuntu/).
The problem is that when i try the kube-up, after creating the binaries, i get the following error:

```
Deploying master and node on machine 10.86.108.150
make-ca-cert.sh                                                          100% 4136     4.0KB/s   00:00
easy-rsa.tar.gz                                                          100%   42KB  42.4KB/s   00:00
config-default.sh                                                        100% 5438     5.3KB/s   00:00
util.sh                                                                  100%   29KB  28.9KB/s   00:00
kubelet.conf                                                             100%  644     0.6KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy.conf                                                          100%  684     0.7KB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                  100% 2158     2.1KB/s   00:00
kube-proxy                                                               100% 2233     2.2KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager.conf                                             100%  744     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler.conf                                                      100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver.conf                                                      100%  674     0.7KB/s   00:00
etcd.conf                                                                100%  709     0.7KB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                           100% 2358     2.3KB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler                                                           100% 2360     2.3KB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                     100% 2073     2.0KB/s   00:00
kube-controller-manager                                                  100% 2672     2.6KB/s   00:00
reconfDocker.sh                                                          100% 2082     2.0KB/s   00:00
etcdctl                                                                  100%   12MB  12.3MB/s   00:00
kube-apiserver                                                           100%   58MB  58.2MB/s   00:00
kube-scheduler                                                           100%   42MB  42.0MB/s   00:00
etcd                                                                     100%   14MB  13.8MB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                 100%   11MB  10.8MB/s   00:01
kube-controller-manager                                                  100%   52MB  51.8MB/s   00:00
kubelet                                                                  100%   60MB  60.3MB/s   00:00
kube-proxy                                                               100%   35MB  34.8MB/s   00:01
flanneld                                                                 100%   11MB  10.8MB/s   00:00
flanneld.conf                                                            100%  577     0.6KB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                 100% 2121     2.1KB/s   00:00
flanneld.conf                                                            100%  568     0.6KB/s   00:00
flanneld                                                                 100% 2131     2.1KB/s   00:00
sudo: unable to resolve host kubernetes-master
etcd start/stopping
**Error:  client: etcd cluster is unavailable or misconfigured
error #0: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: getsockopt: connection refused
error #1: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:4001: getsockopt: connection refused**
```

Thank You for all your answers

Comment: after restaring kube-controller-manager and try the kube-up.sh again i get the following error: cannot create regular file ‘/opt/bin/kube-controller-manager’: Text file busy

Comment: Create an etcd cluster using the coreos manual by hand and try kube-up again.

Comment: You have to run kube-down.sh before running kube-up.sh again because some files could have been locked by processes. Can you see any error on /var/log/upstart/etcd.log file?

Comment: I am also getting same error, please help me to find solution

Answer (score 0):

Use kubeadm to seupt kubernetes clutter. It is stable now and is the recommended approach. You can have single node cluster initially and can be scaled out if you get spare nodes in future.